# Facebook Feed Dialog link format

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed

I have the following code on my website:

```
<a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'><img style="width: 27px; height: 27px; border: 0px;" src="{$baseurl}/images/fb_m.png"/></a>
<p id='msg'></p>
{literal}
<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "xxx", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      display: 'iframe',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
{/literal}
```

The links on my website are in the following format:

```
{$baseurl}/post/{$posts[i].PID}
```

I was trying to add this string in the "link:" section however it does not share the correct link.

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks

Ok, I managed to insert the link correctly. Here is how the link parameter should look:

```
link: '{/literal}{$baseurl}/post/{$posts[i].PID}{literal}',
```

Now the popup script posts a correct link such as http://mysite.com/post/1234. However another problem occurred. My website's page is a grid layout, something like pinterest style. Each post  has its own link. The script however shares the last post in the grid, no matter on which post I click the share button. If I use the share button as a link, such as:

> ```
> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u={$baseurl}/post/{$posts[i].PID}"       onclick=”return fbs_click()” target=”_blank”>share</a>
> ```

the correct post is shared.

I need to use the popup feed dialog instead, with the correct link. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _"however it does not share the correct link"_ - and now you want us to guess what happens instead?

Comment: It shares "{$baseurl}/post/{$posts[i].PID}" instead. This should be rendered as http://mysite.com/post/1234 - for example.

Comment: Then obviously your template system (which ever one you are using) is not rendering out the correct value.

Comment: That is not the case. The links are rendered just fine anywhere on my pages, apart from the facebook code.

Comment: I think I am not inserting it correctly in the code, at least link: '{$baseurl}/post/{$posts[i].PID}', does not work.

Comment: You should read up on what `{literal}` does in the documentation …